# Needs help for writing a part of code according to business case

Tags: apex, trigger

I am a newbie in Apex programming and trying to implement the following business case:

1. We have three record types on object Account: one for recommendators, another for students and another for professors
2. Professors and students can become Recommendators (someone who recommends others to study in the university)
3. The field Recommendator is a checkbox on the Account object, but it is only displayed for students and professors, which will have a community in the future.
4. If the identification number or the email or both given on the web for for recommendators coincide with the ones on a specific account Student or Professor, the checkbox Reccomendator should be set.

So, I was just tempting to write a code, but as my knowledge in APEX is rudimentary, I need some help here, how can I implement this by code. My beginning is:

```
    Set<String> setIdentNumbers = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> setEmailAddresses = new Set<String>(); 


    for(Account cuenta : cuentas){
            setIdentNumbers.add(cuenta.DNI__c); 
            setEmailAddresses.add( cuenta.personEmail );

    }

    System.debug('*********** AccountTriggerHanlder HandleBefore /////////// setIdentNumbers '+setIdentNumbers);

    System.debug('*********** AccountTriggerHanlder HandleBefore /////////// setEmailAddresses '+setEmailAddresses);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, you asking help to write entire code for you?

Comment: It looks like you will need to use a trigger for this. You will need to check the Trigger.olMap as well to accomplish what you are looking for. An idea will be to iterate through a Map that contains only the recommenders and compare them with the Trigger.new. You can do this on a before insert and before update trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, Santanu. It's not my intention to have someone coding for me, that's not the way I can learn. In the meantime I have been implementing it with maps and before insert and befor update. If something doesn't work in a specific part of my code, I will be wrting here.

Comment: If you are new to writing apex code, you should try some of the [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trail/force_com_dev_beginner). They're a good way to start learning apex.